# WPF Generating 1 row with 2 ComboBoxes + 1 Watermark On each click of the button

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, code-behind, dynamically-generated

So Currently I have had success in generating a single row of duplicate elements from the codebehind on button_click. However I need them to generate every time the button is clicked . I.e. for each click generate + 1 more row.
Here's my code snippet on how it happens to generate :

```
// Items to populate Simulator Transaction Type List!r
private class Item 
{
    public string Name;

    public Item(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Generates the text shown in the combo box
        return Name;
    }
}

public void btnAddSimFields_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    var newTypeBox = new ComboBox();
    {
        newTypeBox.Height = 22;
        newTypeBox.Width = 137;
        newTypeBox.Margin = new Thickness(10, 90, 323, 0);
        newTypeBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        newTypeBox.Text = "Select an Action...";
        newTypeBox.IsEditable = true;
        newTypeBox.Items.Add(new Item("Buy"));
        newTypeBox.Items.Add(new Item("Sell"));
        newTypeBox.Items.Add(new Item("Sell Full Amount"));
    }
    var newCoinBox = new ComboBox();
    {
        newCoinBox.Height = 22;
        newCoinBox.Width = 137;
        newCoinBox.Text = "Select a coin";
        newCoinBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        newCoinBox.Margin = new Thickness(166, 90, 167, 0);
        newCoinBox.ItemsSource = cmbListCoins.Items;
        newCoinBox.IsEditable = true;

    }

    var newWaterMark = new WatermarkTextBox();
    {
        newWaterMark.Height = 22;
        newWaterMark.Width = 120;
        newWaterMark.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        newWaterMark.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        newWaterMark.Margin = new Thickness(323, 90, 27, 0);
        newWaterMark.Watermark = "Quantity...";
    }


    gridSimBoxes.Children.Add(newTypeBox);
    gridSimBoxes.Children.Add(newCoinBox);
    gridSimBoxes.Children.Add(newWaterMark);
}
```

So here I add them right they generate all's fine and dandy. My general question is how do I keep adding them on each click , I'm debating over a foreach or a for loop. I'm quite stuck. They're also supposed to be able to be bound to a set of resources that are available globally.

Thanks in advance,

Victor,
Lost Intern

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually create the two comboboxes and the watermark on each click. But as their margin is always put at the same values on each click.. you simply stack the item over the older ones at the exact same place so it 'appears" that you don't create anything after each click.

Try to change your Grid definition into your xaml with something like this :

```
        <Grid x:Name="gridSimBoxes">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="StackpanelTypeBox"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="StackpanelCoinBox"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="StackpanelWatermark"/>
            </StackPanel>                
        </Grid>
```

Then in your code add the item you create to each stackpanel :

```
    StackpanelTypeBox.Children.Add(newTypeBox);
    StackpanelCoinBox.Children.Add(newCoinBox);
    StackpanelWatermark.Children.Add(newWaterMark);
```

You will see that you already created all the three items after each click :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT works , however problem number 2 arose.
I have to now bind them to an ItemsSource (That's finished).
But i also need to reference them in an IF/else statement as their selected value will create differences in the function. So for example if one of the children has "Buy" in them 
try
{
// Some code
}
catch
{
// Some Exception
}

Comment: This answer may be much longer, i would highly recommand you to avoid doing such business in full code behind. In my opinion i would create some collection of entities with an Item and buyingStatus as a boolean then bind them in the xaml to an ItemControl. Then you will be able to do the code you want in the setter of the boolean 'BuyingStatus"

Comment: But if you want to stick to your code behind way, one possible workaround could be to add a fourth column with a checkbox, store somewhere (maybe in the Checkbox Tag) the Item object and register manually the checked/unchecked event. Then in the checked/unchecked event method you can get back the item related to the checkbox through the sender parameter (must be cast into Checkbox to access the tag property) but it's really dirty

Comment: Jonathan Perennes 

I am not quite sure what you meant with the first comment. Is there any source you can point me to or an example of a sort?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial : http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/

Comment: Thanks I did that yesterday before the comment, however , it is upon the click function where I want them to generate and  I was not able to position and generate all the components . I reused the stackpanel suggestion and .add(ed) Children there( the 2x Combobox-es + 1x Watermark) .
I'll try it again and post what I get so far. Again Thank you so much for the responsivenes I really appreciate it! I'm only an intern and i need all the help I can get.
Thank you again!